# Automatically adding ServiceProviders laravel to config/app.php and autoload config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.3

So I am using laravel 5.3 and I have just created my first bare package for a CMS that I have created.
It works fine however I don't want to be adding the to composer.json autoload manually i want this to be done automatically from a drag and drop or a select option in the admin area eg:

```
"autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "database"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/",
                "Corium\\MediaManager\\" : "packages/corium/mediaManager/src"
            }
        },
```

Then I want this: `Corium\MediaManager\MediaManagerServiceProvider::class,` added to the config/app.php provider array with out the end user needing to enter the backend code. What is the best way of doing this because i cant work out how to get this to work.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registering services with the application should almost always be done within a service provider. Service providers, as you know, are registered in `config/app.php`, so you will have to manually register at least one provider. However, within that provider, you have access to an `app` property that is an application instance, which you can call the `register` method on to register additional providers. This way you can have one provider pre-registered and register additional providers as you need them in code.

The documentation on [Writing Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers#writing-service-providers) should get you started.

Comment: Ok so if I have one over arching Package service provider should i then store what other packages i have in a database table and create a loop to run through and register them or is there a better way?

Comment: I would probably put them in another config file inside the config directory or something like that. But that's completely up to you. Still not sure why you want to dynamically load the services, I feel like your CMS would run faster just registering all of them initially and still only using the ones that you need.